# can you change the way get method makes links for django?

Tags: python, html, django, get

I'm using django for a website that has a searchbar setup with a simple form:

```
<form method="get" action="/browse">
    <div class="input-group col-md-12">
        <input type="text" name="searchquery" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Search" style="margin-right:1vw; border-radius: 5px;"/>

        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">
                {% fontawesome_icon 'search' color='white' %}
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

This creates url's like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/browse/?searchquery=<searchquery>
```

However I've setup my django url like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/browse/<searchquery>/
```

I would like to use the second url (as it just looks a lot better in my opinion).

Is there a way I can make my form do this?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a question about Django. The browser simply can't do this with an HTML form. The action attribute of the form is set when it is loaded.

You could possibly write some JavaScript to make it do this. But that would be the wrong thing to do. Queries like search *should* be part of the querystring, not the URL.

Comment: allright thanks. now I have the url like: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/browse/?searchquery=test` but is there a way I can get rid of the slash after `browse` and have it like: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/browse?searchquery=test`

Comment: Yes, don't put one in the URL pattern in urls.py.

Comment: that does not seem to work... I now get an error that django has no url for it...